# Parse JSON objects by Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, rest, api

I am new into Javascript and actually I'm facing following problem.
I get JSON-object by calling an API. I get more than one object, that is fine. The objects are like this:

```
{"version": 1.0.1,
 "id": 125,
 "name": "Elmos App Test",
 "creationDate": "2017-05-28",
},
{"version": 1.0.4,
 "id": 25,
 "name": "Elmos App Prod",
 "creationDate": "2017-05-25",
},
{"version": 1.1,
 "id": 14,
 "name": "Elmos App Int",
 "creationDate": "2017-04-23",
}
```

I hope it is not too difficult to identify the JSON here. MY problem is now to save the three names in one variable.

Response of call should be like --> "Your apps are Elmos App Test Elmos App Prod Elmos App Int"

I actually have following Javascriptcode:

```
function getJSON(callback){
        request.get(url(), function(error, response, body){
            var d = JSON.parse(body);
            var result = d.name;//query for result
            if (result > null){
                callback(result);}
            else
         {
            callback("ERROR");
         }
    });
```

As you can see i try to save the name into the var result.
Hope someone can help me out there. Thank you.

Comment: I hope your first code block has `[ ]` around it.

Comment: So loop over them and concatenate a string.

Comment: If that's the complete response then it's not valid JSON.

Comment: `result > null`, huh?

Comment: also need to quote the float numbers so your response should look like:
[{"version": "1.0.1", "id": 125, "name": "Elmos App Test", "creationDate": "2017-05-28",},{"version": "1.0.4", "id": 25, "name": "Elmos App Prod", "creationDate": "2017-05-25",},{"version": "1.1", "id": 14, "name": "Elmos App Int", "creationDate": "2017-04-23"}]

Comment: @Liquidchrome indeed the JSON looks like you said

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Array#map()` to only get the names and then `join()` to concatenate them

```js
const array = [{"version": "1.0.1", "id": 125, "name": "Elmos App Test", "creationDate": "2017-05-28", }, {"version": "1.0.4", "id": 25, "name": "Elmos App Prod", "creationDate": "2017-05-25", }, {"version": "1.1", "id": 14, "name": "Elmos App Int", "creationDate": "2017-04-23" }],
  name = array.map(a=>a.name).join(' ');
console.log(name);
```

Comment: But obviously you stored the JSON in the array... how can i store the response in the array?

Comment: Don't you already have an array ? What kind of data do you get from `request.get(url)`?